# Laravel - Override parent constructor from extended class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm extending a controller from a package so I can edit it and avoid losing changes when I update using composer. So far everything works fine but I'm having an issue with the constructor.

My original class has this:

```
class UserRegisterService
{


    public function __construct(UserSignupValidator $v = null)
    {
        //unrelated stuff here
        Event::listen('service.activated',
                      'Jacopo\Authentication\Services\UserRegisterService@sendActivationEmailToClient');
    }
}
```

The extended controller is:

```
use Jacopo\Authentication\Services\UserRegisterService;
use Jacopo\Authentication\Validators\UserSignupValidator;


class CustomUserRegisterService extends UserRegisterService
{

    public function __construct(UserSignupValidator $v = null)
    {
        //unrelated stuff here
        Event::listen('service.activated',
                      'CustomUserRegisterService@sendActivationEmailToClient');
    }
```

I have basically the same thing, the changes on my extended class are inside CustomUserRegisterService@sendActivationEmailToClient (basically I want to send an email different than in the original controller, using mandrill and a custom template).

The event is firing and both functions are being called, so I get a duplicate email when the user is activated (that's the event in this case). I only want the constructor on my custom class to be invoked, and the other one needs to be ignored.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:** As suggested in the comments, I commented the Event::listen in the original constructed and that solved the issue, only one email was sent. But of course that doesn't solve the problem that it will get uncommented as soon as I update.

Adding return false; at the end of CustomUserRegisterService@sendActivationEmailToClient didn't work either, only commented the event in the constructor did the trick.

Comment: Assuming you are not callent `parent::__constructor` in your child class, the parent's listener shouldn't be fired. Is it possible that the parent class `UserRegisterService` is being instantiated somewhere else in your code? And are you sure that it's the parent listener that's firing, and not the child listener that's firing twice? (Remove one of them to check.) Finally, you could `return false` from your listener to stop event propagation (though it would be better to figure out why it's happening and resolve that).

Comment: the emails are different (the whole point of having a custom controller was that), so I know one comes from the old controller, maybe it's not from the constructor, I'll test further and comment, thanks for your input

Comment: In your parent constructor, change the event listener to a closure that contains `throw new Exception();`, then look back over the stack trace to see where the event is being fired.

Comment: Any changes I do to the parent constructor will get deleted after I do composer update. That's the main issue with this.

Comment: No, this is just for debugging. That way you can see exactly where the listener in the parent constructor is being called from, and isolate if there might be an instance of the parent class `UserRegisterService` being created somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you dont call parent::__construct() in your CustomUserRegisterService class UserRegisterService __construct will not get executed. But you will have to implement  "unrelated stuff" in UserRegisterService in your CustomUserRegisterService class __constructor.

```js
class A {
 public function __construct($v = "")
 {
  echo "A's constructor";
 }
}


class B extends A{
 public function __construct()
 {
        //parent::__construct();

  echo "B's constructor";
 }
}


$b = new B();
```

Output : B's constructor

As for your example

Ok, heres a thought, but first please check whether you are instantiating  UserRegisterService somewhere in the code. if so then you have to make it singleton. in UserRegisterService class Event::listent it says when it triggers 'service.activated' run sendActivationEmailToClient of UserRegisterService. So whenever it triggers 'service.activated' system instantiate a object of UserRegisterService then run the sendActivationEmailToClient function. Now the problem is when ever system creates the UserRegisterService instance it runs the constructor. which means it adds another listener to the Event pool. IMO what you have to do is make user laravel is not loading (instantiating)  UserRegisterService or CustomUserRegisterService  more than once.

Eg:

```js
//AClass.php in model folder

class AClass
{

    public function __construct($v = "")
    {
        echo "A's constructor <br />";
        
        Event::listen('a.run', 'A@hi');
    }

    public static function hi()
    {
         echo "Its me, A's event <br />";
    }
    

}

//BClass.php in model folder

class BClass extends AClass
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        //parent::__construct();
        echo "B's constructor <br />";
        
        Event::listen('a.run', 'BClass@hi');
        
    }

    public static function hi()
    {
        echo "Its me, B's event <br />";
    }

}




//in app/routes.php or in your service provider

App::singleton('ObjB', function(){
    return new BClass();
});

APP::bind('BClass', function(){
    return App::make('ObjB');
});


//test the events
Route::get('/',  function(){
    $b = App::make('ObjB');
    
    echo "1st event trigger ------------ <br/>";
    Event::fire('a.run');
    
    echo "2nd event trigger ------------ <br/>";
    Event::fire('a.run');
    
    echo "3rd event trigger ------------ <br/>";
    Event::fire('a.run');
});
```

I hope this will help you. I'm testing this in laravel 4.2, and its working fro me. let me know your result. thanks

Comment: I'm not calling the parent constructor inside CustomUserRegisterService, the "unrelated stuff" are variables, they are in both constructor. So if I understand you correctly, the parent constructor shouldn't be executed? Maybe I'm missing something else in the rest of the class but I would say the event is firing up the two functions

Comment: well, if CustomUserRegisterService not calling the parent constructor then it should be something else. try commenting parent class Event::listen and see whether its still sending you two emails.

Comment: I commented the event in the original event::listen and I only got one email, so I'm confused. Both constructors are being executed here. The return false; that damiani suggested didn't work either.